# Stopping a margin transition at its initial point

Tags: css

Alright, here's what I have a nifty little scroller (they've been done to death but I wanted to take my hand at making one) and I want it to scroll to the left for X amount of pixels, which is no problem.  The problem is, if the user hovers over the left side and starts scrolling the text back, I want it to stop at its initial starting point.

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 98;
  border: 3px solid 2a3439;
  background-color: #353839;
}

.scroller {
  color: white;
  width: 1980px;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  transition: all 2s linear 10s;
  -moz-transition: all 2s linear 10s;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s linear 10s;
}

.go-left:hover~.scroller {
  margin-left: -250px;
  transition: all 2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s linear ;
}

.go-left {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.go-right {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 300px
}

.go-right:hover+.scroller {
  margin-left: 250px;
  transition: all 2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  Height: 490px;
}
```

In that example, if you hover to the left I don't want it to move past it's starting point, so clamping it.  You can see the working model on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Kaanha/puy6t4og/51/

This wouldn't be hard using some java, but the main thing here is, I need it to be pure CSS only.  No java.

Thanks in advance for all help!

Comment: margin:0 instead of -250px ?

Comment: I tried that, it won't scroll to the right at all.

Comment: the srcoll right is controlled by increasing the margin, https://jsfiddle.net/puy6t4og/57/

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Scrolling right and left works fine.  The problem is I want it to STOP scrolling right when it reaches the point it started at.  So, it starts at it's current origin, scrolls left some arbitrary distance.  if the user hovers over the invisible trigger point on the right side and starts the scrolling back...I want it to stop at its origin.  if it's already at its origin, I want it to do nothing.

Comment: its origin is marign:0, am not sure what you mean ...

Comment: If you hover over the hotspot to scroll it to the right, it scrolls past its origins.  I do not want it to go PAST its origin when scrolling right.  I'm not sure how to detect when it's hit margin of zero, using just pure CSS

Comment: well, am confused, you talk about right scroll and the origin is in the left ... you are not confusing left with right? are you able to show us an example with fixed values how you want it?

Comment: I did show you an example.  If you hover over the left hotspot, the text scrolls in that direction, it works perfectly.  Now, if you hover the right hotspot, it scrolls right, however, it will scroll past its origin.  I'm not wanting it to scroll past its origin point.  If the user has not scrolled it to the left, I do not want it to move if you hover over the right hot spot.  If the user has scrolled to the left and they choose to scroll back to the right, I don't want it to go beyond its origin.  All content will move from right to left, scrolling past and then back to the origin.